# Next js server page without javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hi guys I would like to know how can I serve html page in Next Js page without additional javascript.I would need this because I will display that page for users that do not have smartphones that haver regular old phones for example symbian or any other old phone.

I know that in next.js you can use the "public" directory in your root directory to serve static assets.

But is there some other way ? Will it use too much resurces on old phones because it users too much js

Comment: Read https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering

Comment: I know it not NextJs but Remix is growing a lot and it has exactly what you need. You might want to give a look: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/disabling-javascript.

Comment: @juliomalves so it is ok to put it in public folder ?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to put an HTML file in the `public` folder, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer from [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) docs:

*By default, Next.js pre-renders every page. This means that Next.js generates HTML for each page in advance, instead of having it all done by client-side JavaScript. Pre-rendering can result in better performance and SEO.*

*Each generated HTML is associated with minimal JavaScript code necessary for that page. When a page is loaded by the browser, its JavaScript code runs and makes the page fully interactive. (This process is called hydration.)*

That means if your page is full static there will be no Javascript shipped to the client.

See also [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props).

Comment: Do you have a reproduction of this? This was not my understanding of how Next.js works (`/pages` router or `/app`) and I haven't been able to reproduce this.